# Jquery .on or .click not working, alert does not appear

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#top").on('click',function(){
        alert('I am here');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 'slow');
        return false;
});
```

and when I click the button (which is generated by jquery, but before the click code)

```
html += "<p><a href='javascript:;' id='top'>Back to Top</a></p>";
```

the alert does not appear. I have also tried this:

```
$("#top").click(function(){
            alert('I am here');
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 'slow');
            return false;
    });
```

I have tried moving this code into the footer, but that didnt do anything and this code is wrapped in the `$(document).ready(function(){`

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are creating elements dynamically, You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', "#top", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performance.

Comment: Well, even though there already are two upvotes, it worth to mention: _when I click the button (which is generated by jquery, but before the click code)_. For all that I understood it is like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk9bLxbb/), so it should work without event delegation.

Comment: @Regent, I totally agree with your example, if thats the scenario the OP's will surely work.